# Unable to cast object of type exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm working with ASP.NET and EF 6.1. I'm trying to seed the database with some objects but I get the following exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[B]' to type 'B'.
```

when I try to create an user using the user manager.

All of the database initialization is done in the seed method. I simplified the classes as there are a lot of parameters in some of them.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public User() : base()
    {
        Bs = new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}


public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Bs = new HashSet<B>();
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

protected override void Seed(myContext context)
{
    var a = new A;
    var b = new B;
    A.Bs.Add(B);
    context.As.Add(A);
    var userStore = new UserStore<User>(context);
    var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);
    var user = new User
    {
        UserName = "username",
        A = a
    };
    userManager.Create(user, "password!");
    user.Bs.Add(B);
    base.Seed(context);
}
```

I've been at it for quite some time and really can't figure out why this is isn't working. If I don't seed the database, there aren't any problems. Seeding the database without creating the user also doesn't give me any trouble, but once I try to create an user this happens. Don't think it has anything to do with how the relationships are looped together, I removed the cascading deletions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same problem, removing the many to many cascade delete convention did the trick. Just add this code to the context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```